# C# carousel using sql as the data source

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic, carousel

How can you create a carousel using dynamic content instead of specifying the images.

We are wanting to create a form for users to upload images to a directory on the server and store the path in a sql Db, what is the process for obtaining the data to the use in the front end.

Any help would be great.

Comment: "Soapbox moment" - If you're going to have a database, not sure why you'd want to store the images as files on the server, rather than in the database. Everything in one place for data access is often a cleaner, easier to manage design.

Comment: Thanks - if what is the process of obtaining the data from the database then assigning to the carousel? Do you need to call your select statement and assign to a datatable then build the carousel based on the values from the data table? Thanks

Comment: That depends on a number of things... Are you implementing a custom carousel or using a third party component? Is this a web or desktop application? What RDBMS are you using for the data store? What have you got so far and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: This question, as currently stated is a bit too broad for this forum. You should be researching how to do what you want to accomplish, rather than asking us to do the research for you. Once you have some concrete questions, return and we will be happy to help however we can.

Comment: I am going to be using bootstrap carousel and it's a web application. I am struggling with the process after obtaining the data, i am unsure of how to store and break down the data after the selecting prior to assigning it to the carousel. As I have only used sql data against a grid view previous. Thanks

Comment: How experienced are you with building web applications?

Comment: Very new to it. I have done bits with importing whole series of data to gridviews and details view using query parameters etc. but this is my first time manipulating the data and changing the presentation before outputting.

Comment: Since the carousel component you will be using is client-side (JavaScript/jQuery), and client-side code inherently has no direct access to server-side data, what you are proposing to do will require some relatively advanced concepts. I would suggest you follow the examples/tutorials and get the carousel working correctly with static images (to get familiar with how it works) then move on to trying to store and retrieve images dynamically. You are going to need to use AJAX calls from the client-side to a web service on the server-side to access the data.

Comment: This assumes that the carousel component is not specifically coded to get the images from a server-side folder and can accept dynamic input of images. If that is not so, then you will need to have a process running on the server that periodically moves a new set of images into the designated folder (this would take the form of a WIndows Service).

Comment: Thanks Kevin - So how I am currently tackling this is... creating a datatable in the code behind based on my query (for the time being I have just added some URLs to some test images) then databinding this to a repeater. I am using                                                                    <img src="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Images") %>" alt="" height="200px" width="200px" />                                                                         within the item template.

Comment: In high level would this be a good way of obtaining the data as a datatable  then binding it to the control on the front end? Without worrying about AJAX at the moment? Thanks

Comment: As long as that works, I don't see any inherent problem with it.